# "neither of whom" vs "none of whom"

Tags: determiners

Here is the sentence:

> *Several prisoners escaped last night, **none of whom/neither of whom**
>   has been caught so far*.

*In my opinion, I'd use 'none of whom', since we are talking about several people who escaped.*

Which one would you rather use in this particular context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

**Neither of whom** would apply to two individuals.

**None of whom** would apply to three or more.